# Does SO_REUSEPORT option work on Linux for multicast sockets?

Tags: c, network-programming

I set the socket option SO_REUSEPORT for a multicast socket, but I got errno 92 "Protocol not available".
BTW I defined  SO_REUSEPORT on socket.h file "/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h".

Comment: (a) If you showed your code, you might have gotten a better and more timely response. (b) If you edited a system header to add the flag, then it has no chance of working.  The system headers should be regarded as sacrosanct — holy writ not to be defiled by mortal hand — until you know enough about how to rebuild the kernel and modify the device drivers to handle the new socket option.  If you mean "I found `SO_REUSEPORT` in `/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h`", then you have a reasonable question.